# Get rows changed between two dates (latest and previous)

Tags: mariadb, order-by, limits

I have a table `_sync_history` with this data:

```
+----+----------------+---------------------+
| id | object_name    | sync_time           |
+----+----------------+---------------------+
|  1 | territory      | 2015-07-21 22:29:02 |
|  2 | user           | 2015-07-21 22:29:19 |
|  3 | userterritory  | 2015-07-21 22:29:38 |
|  4 | account        | 2015-07-21 22:30:05 |
|  5 | accountshare   | 2015-07-21 22:39:04 |
|  6 | address_vod__c | 2015-07-22 00:47:38 |
|  7 | group          | 2015-07-22 01:23:30 |
|  8 | recordtype     | 2015-07-22 01:23:51 |
|  9 | user           | 2015-07-23 13:04:20 |
| 10 | account        | 2015-07-23 13:04:59 |
+----+----------------+---------------------+
```

I want to get the rows on `user` between `2015-07-21 22:29:19` and `2015-07-23 13:04:20` meaning the rows between last sync_time and previous sync_time for a given `object_name`. I was doing this:

```
SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE lastmodifieddate > (SELECT sync_time FROM `_sync_history` WHERE object_name='user' ORDER BY sync_time ASC LIMIT 1)
```

But that will give me just the ones from last sync_time and above which is not right, how do I get the ones I need?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to find both times, one using what you have (`LIMIT 1`) and the second using `LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1`.

I'd also use `ORDER BY ... DESC`, not `ASC`. Your wording suggests you want the rows between the **last** 2 appearnces of `'user'`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM user 
WHERE lastmodifieddate > 
        (SELECT sync_time 
         FROM _sync_history 
         WHERE object_name = 'user' 
         ORDER BY sync_time DESC 
         LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1
        )
  AND lastmodifieddate <
        (SELECT sync_time 
         FROM _sync_history 
         WHERE object_name = 'user' 
         ORDER BY sync_time DESC 
         LIMIT 1 OFFSET 0
        ) ;
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do it using [`UDV`:](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/user-variables.html)

```
#MIN sync_time of user
SET @StartDate=(SELECT MIN(sync_time) FROM test._sync_history WHERE object_name='user' LIMIT 0,1);

#MAX sync_time of user
SET @EndDate=(SELECT MAX(sync_time) FROM test._sync_history WHERE object_name='user' LIMIT 0,1);

#Query:
SELECT * FROM test.user WHERE lastmodifieddate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate;
```

Answer (score -1):

From what I gather I would do:

```
SELECT *
FROM user
WHERE lastmodifieddate IN ( SELECT min(sync_time), max(sync_time)
                            FROM _sync_history
                            WHERE object_name= "user" );
```

Comment: This is not valid syntax. You would have to use `UNION ALL` in the subquery and have SELECT lists with a single column (MIN and MAX respectively).

Comment: You are right. My apology. Is this what you mean?                                                             SELECT *
    FROM user
    WHERE lastmodifieddate IN ( SELECT min(sync_time)
                                FROM _sync_history
                                WHERE object_name= "user" 
           UNION ALL
                                SELECT max(sync_time)
                                FROM _sync_history
                                WHERE object_name= "user");

Comment: `in` finds values in a set, not in between two values. For that you would need `between <a> and <b>` but that won't work with a subquery in this way.

Comment: Yes, @Colin'tHart is right. In Postgres, you could use the "element is contained by" operator for ranges, with something like `lastmodifieddate <@ (SELECT tsrange(min(sync_time), max(sync_time)) FROM _sync_history ...)` but MySQL does not have these types and operators.